# .htaccess hide extension while forcing www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have the following htaccess file, which hides the php extension and forces all URLs to use www:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

For the first part the credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054107/how-to-mask-extension-in-url/2054115#2054115) and the second one to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648524/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-force-www-on-multiple-domains/648541#648541).

This works perfect in most cases, however there is one problem. When a user tries to go to http://example.com/foo (or instead of "foo", whatever other page) it redirects to http://www.example.com/foo.php .

How can I make it redirect to http://www.example.com/foo , that is, whithout the .php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the order of your rules. First external redirect then the internal one. Have your code like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tested it and works fine on my end.

Answer (score 1):

What is "foo" in this case, a file?  If so, this works:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If you want to exclude "foo" specifically,

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If you're trying to use a web framework, then they probably want you to redirect all non-file and non-directory requests to something like index.php.

Edit: Try swapping and consolidating the two sections:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

<IfModule rewrite_module>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use "foo" as a [generic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) page. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: In that case, the first part of my answer (`!-f`) is what you want.

Comment: I added the first part to my .htaccess, but it still added the .php when it redirected.

Comment: You'll have to provide more concrete detail.  You've created a real file on the server?

Comment: Yes, there is a file named foo.php in the server. It works well on www.example.com/foo , but if I type example.com/foo (without the www) it redirects to www.example.com/foo.php . The .php part is not supposed to show.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Now URLs without the .php don't work at all, and there are no redirects.

Comment: Sorry, I'd probably have to fidget with it in person.  Hopefully someone else spots the problem.